# Is there any Genetic Programming code written R

Tags: r, genetic-programming

I'm interesting in evolutionary algorithms. I have tested genetic algorithms with R but has someone tried with genetic programming? Do you know, if there are code somewhere written in R.

Comment: Have you posted the same message in April, 2007: http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/e2/help/07/04/13635.html

Comment: `library("sos"); findFn("{genetic algorithm}")`

Answer (score 13):

I'm not aware of anything on CRAN for genetic programming in particular, although there is some work being done on the problem.  In particular, have a look at [the RGP package](https://rsymbolic.org/projects/show/rgp) that is still in development.

Otherwise, have a look at [the RFreak package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RFreak/index.html), which is a wrapper for the ["Free Evolutionary Algorithm Kit"](http://sourceforge.net/projects/freak427/).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at genalg, at GA and at galgo

Comment: [Genetic algorithms are not Genetic programming!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819977/what-are-the-differences-between-genetic-algorithms-and-genetic-programming)

Answer (score 1):

There is a new package available:
[gramEvol: Grammatical Evolution for R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gramEvol/index.html)

> A native R implementation of grammatical evolution (GE). GE
> facilitates the discovery of programs that can achieve a desired goal.
> This is done by performing an evolutionary optimisation over a
> population of R expressions generated via a user-defined context-free
> grammar (CFG) and cost function.

You can find the vignette here:
[Grammatical Evolution: A Tutorial using gramEvol](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gramEvol/vignettes/ge-intro.pdf)

**UPDATE**: I posted an article on my blog about it:
[Symbolic Regression, Genetic Programming… or if Kepler had R](https://blog.ephorie.de/symbolic-regression-genetic-programming-or-if-kepler-had-r).