# R template for evolutionary algorithms?

Tags: r, user-input, evolutionary-algorithm

Is there a ready template to run evolutionary\genetic algorithms in R?

I am interested in a code that would allow me to add graphical output and user input between iterations.

Thanks for reading!

p.s. found this posting [Is there any Genetic Programming code written R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681227/is-there-any-genetic-programming-code-written-r)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about genetic programming code written in R, but there is a program called HeuristicLab you can use. 
There you can add an External Evaluator in R code and there you can add your graphical output.

Here is a link on how to do it:
http://dev.heuristiclab.com/trac/hl/core/wiki/UsersHowtosOptimizingExternalApplications

Its an open source program and the staff that wrote it usually answers any question you have very quickly.

Here is the download page: http://dev.heuristiclab.com/trac/hl/core/wiki

good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Yep, i think http://rsymbolic.org/projects/show/rgp is exactly what you're looking for.